# applying a measure filter with date using DAX query

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am trying to get the customers whose Amount(Measure) is greater than 1000 for the given date period.

But the results I get are less than 1000 even. Does the filter query in DAX doesn't work for Measure with a date?

The DAX query is:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
Customer[CustomerID],
FILTER( ALL( Customer[CustomerID] ), [Amount] > 1000 ),
KEEPFILTERS( FILTER( ALL( 'Date'[Date] ), 'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2020,1,1) && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2020,1,7) )),
"Amount", [Amount])
```

Any help on this would be grateful. I would like to get the customers who have the Amount(Measure) greater than 1000 for given date period.

Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ubzeuYs5ptvbkSvO0K16dPFxBf-2zz4C?usp=sharing .Sorry, please try.

Comment: @Mik  I have requested access to this file. One more thing to notice, it works fine if  I don't consider the date filter. As soon as I add a date filter it messes up.

Comment: Then add to a Calculate , ALL(Date) as a last argument, as in my answer. You can mark the Date table as dateTable, then this ALL(Date) will be added automatically while executing the code.

Comment: How do you filter dates? Can you add a screenshot? and How do you get the max/min dates int the code?

Comment: @Mik This works. Thank you so much. I was filtering the date like this:
KEEPFILTERS( FILTER( ALL( 'Date'[Date] ), 'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2011,1,1) && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2011,1,31) ))

Comment: Is the case is Solved? If you are waiting for  @Ozan Sen it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR WithAmount =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        VALUES(Customer[ID])
        ,"myAmount",CALCULATE(
                        [Amount]
                        ,'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2020,1,1) && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2020,1,7)
                        ,ALL(Date)                   
                    )                     
    )    
RETURN
    FILTER(
        WithAmount
        ,[myAmount]>1000
    )
```

Comment: Hello @Mik, thanks for the reply, but it still returns me the value whose amount value is greater than 1000.

Comment: Hej @priya, your input is - `I would like to get the customers who have the Amount(Measure) greater than 1000 for given date period.` The measure returns this? If not, can you give details which values are not ok?

Comment: Hi @Mik, sorry for my mistake in the previous comment, I am still getting customers whose amount value is less than 1000. The result I am getting looks something like this:
CustomerID        Amount
1                    645.3848
2                    14688.2499
3                     366.0274
4 
5                     3426.7435
6                     4738.276

Comment: Sound strange.I can't understand how it can be possible with the measure. Can you post your code with proposed measure?

Comment: I got a measuregroup or table as Sales which has Sales Amount as column and Amount as Measure.
The Amount(Measure) is calculated as Sum([Sales Amount]).

What I am trying to do is trying to get customer whose Amount is greater than 1000.

So I tried this to get list of customers whose Amount is greater than 1000, but it returns me customers who got less than 1000.

Comment: EVALUATE
VAR SummarizedTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
             Customer, 
             Customer[CustomerID],
             "Amounts", [Amount]
        ), "Amount", [Amount]
    )
 VAR Result = 
 CALCULATETABLE(
  SummarizedTable,
  FILTER(ALL('Date'[Date]),
   'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2020,1,1)
    && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2020,1, 7)
  ),
  FILTER ( ALL ( Customer[CustomerID] ), [Amount] > 1000 )
  )
RETURN
    RESULT

Comment: You doubeled [Amount] columns. If you wil not exclude it from summarize it wont work.

Comment: Why don't you want to try my code as it is?

Comment: I copied your same code and tried that. It lists me all customers even whose amount is less than 1000 in that duration. And some customers it leaves blank value. For example, CustomerID 1 has Amount 366.76 it's returning in your given query.

Comment: Please, can you add a screenshot of the dax query window and result with my code in a DAX Studio. You can add it in an anwser and delete it later.

Comment: I have added the screenshot to your answer above.

Comment: Please, change [Sales amount] to ,[Amount]

Comment: did you pushed run?

Comment: Yes I pushed run, cleared cache and everything and then run the above command.
In SQL if I run this command it gets me correct results:
select CustomerID, SUM(Sales.SalesAmount) from [cdp].Sales where Date >= CONVERT(date, '01-01-2020', 104) AND Date <= CONVERT(date, '07-01-2020', 104)
 GROUP BY cdp.BuyinEvent.CustomerID HAVING SUM(Sales.SalesAmount) > 1000 order by CustomerID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246732/discussion-between-mik-and-priya).

Comment: @Mik Hello, I think You need to change the column reference in your last code. It must be like this: FILTER(WithAmount,Sales[Amount]>1000). Why ? Because you can't refer to a column in a table defined by VAR. You need to put the original table name. I think It will work then.

Comment: Did you see the screenshot?

Comment: @OzanSen, thank you for the idea. It can be a mess with an identical Column name and measure.

Comment: @Mik Yes, Indeed. we do not always create the circumstances ourselves; but the one who offers solutions.

Comment: @OzanSen I know it will be a mess if we got the identical column, but in this case they are not identical names. For ex: In AdventureWorks db we got Internet Sales Amount as measure and Sales Amount as column when I filter as per the date I still get values greater than 1000.

Comment: @Priya Hello, Is it possible to share your model view ? I need to see the relationship between tables to ensure that filter context moves rightly through relationship.

Comment: @OzanSen, Let's carry this discussion here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246772/discussion-between-priya-and-ozan-sen

Comment: @OzanSen the model  can be downloaded from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19XwJaYHVBrakP1v11nGyuvu-lOqy5dnk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

(**Updated**)Please test this measure. I hope It solves your problem.

```
TotalCustomers =
VAR SummarizedTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( SUMMARIZE ( Sales, Customer[CustomerID] ), "Amount", [Amount] )
VAR FiltersAplied =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SummarizedTable,
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
            'Date'[Date] >= DATE ( 2020, 1, 1 )
                && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE ( 2020, 1, 7 )
        ),
        FILTER ( Sales, Sales[Amount] > 1000 )
    )
VAR Result =
    COUNTROWS ( FiltersAplied )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: Hello, @Mik Both the queries don't work. For now, I will consider dummy data i.e. Adventure works dB. Mik I ran your query for that, I got the below data and attached the screenshot to my question. I still get values below 1000. 
In this measure name is Internet Sales Amount (sum of Sales Amount) and column name is Sales Amount.